# How to determine the observations when they are mashed for a PCA plot

Tags: r, plot, pca

I've done a PCA with R using the function *princomp* and the *ggfortify* package. I cannot determine the all the observations at the 4th component (where there is an X25 and 2-4 other observations). Is there a way for me to do this more smoothly where I can distinguish them? I don't care what package to use, I'd just like to see what the observations are much better.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `label.repel=TRUE` from the `ggfortify` package.

An example using the `mtcars` dataset:

**Overlapping labels:**

```
autoplot(prcomp(mtcars),
                  label=T)
```

[image]

**Repelled labels:**

```
autoplot(prcomp(mtcars),
         label=T,label.repel=T)
```

[image]